# Unity jump keep getting faster

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been trying to fix this player script the problem was when it jump it accelerate the player on the ground even in the middle of the air (While it move in a straight line)i think this is more likey those glitchs in the game where player can "Bunny Hop" i want the code to keep moving in the constant speed of 10 but it somehow makes it faster only if the player is jumping

```cs
private void FixedUpdate()
 {

     Body.AddForce(Vector3.right * Walk, ForceMode.Force);
 }  
 private void Update()
 {
     if (TimerLoad > 0)
     {
         TimerLoad -= Time.deltaTime;
         
     }
     else
     {
         
         if ( IsStoppedByWall == false && lives.live >= 0) // and live > 1 so its not -1 lives
         {
             if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
             {
                 if (CanJump == true && JumpCount < 2)
                 {

                     JumpCount ++;
                     Body.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpPower);    
                     Debug.Log(JumpCount);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     CanJump = false;
                 }

             }
             if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
             {
                 Body.AddForce(Vector3.back * Walk, ForceMode.Force);

             }
             else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
             {
                 Body.AddForce(Vector3.forward * Walk, ForceMode.Force);
             }
         }

         else
         {
             Destroy(Body);
             Debug.Log("Stopped");
         }
     }
     
 }
```

what i tried is to find a deaccelerator aka air drag but it failed so i use body.velocity but didnt work either so i just gave up on fixing it

Comment: In `FixedUpdate` you constantly add force no matter what `Body.AddForce(Vector3.right * Walk, ForceMode.Force);` ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Body.AddForce()` try `Body.velocity = new Vector3(10, Body.velocity.y, Body.velocity.z);` set the velocity directly to 10 feel free to change the value if it's too much.